# Connecting FIWARE Orion with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, fiware-orion, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I tried using FIWARE Orion [1] and for the database I used Azure Cosmos DB Mongo API. I followed the steps as outlined in the issue [2]. The contents of the file docker-compose.yml are:

```
 version: "3" 

 services:
   orion:
     image: fiware/orion
     ports:
       - "1026:1026"
     command: -dbhost "mongo-perf-testing.mongo.cosmos.azure.com:10255" -db "fiver_db" -dbuser "mongo-perf-testing" -dbpwd "password" -dbSSL -dbDisableRetryWrites -logLevel DEBUG -t 100
```

When I run the docker container, it starts off okay.

Then I run following queries:

Query: `curl localhost:1026/version`
Response:

```
{
"orion" : {
  "version" : "3.6.0",
  "uptime" : "0 d, 0 h, 9 m, 31 s",
  "git_hash" : "973850279e63d58cb93dff751648af5ec6e05777",
  "compile_time" : "Wed Mar 2 10:34:48 UTC 2022",
  "compiled_by" : "root",
  "compiled_in" : "5e6b6f1167f7",
  "release_date" : "Wed Mar 2 10:34:48 UTC 2022",
  "machine" : "x86_64",
  "doc" : "https://fiware-orion.rtfd.io/en/3.6.0/",
  "libversions": {
     "boost": "1_66",
     "libcurl": "libcurl/7.61.1 OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.33.0",
     "libmosquitto": "2.0.12",
     "libmicrohttpd": "0.9.70",
     "openssl": "1.1",
     "rapidjson": "1.1.0",
     "mongoc": "1.17.4",
     "bson": "1.17.4"
  }
}
}
```

Then I insert an entry using:

Query:

```
'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '
{
    "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:Store:001",
    "type": "Store",
    "address": {
        "type": "PostalAddress",
        "value": {
            "streetAddress": "Bornholmer Straße 65",
            "addressRegion": "Berlin",
            "addressLocality": "Prenzlauer Berg",
            "postalCode": "10439"
        },
        "metadata": {
            "verified": {
                "value": true,
                "type": "Boolean"
            }
        }
    },
    "location": {
        "type": "geo:json",
        "value": {
             "type": "Point",
             "coordinates": [13.3986, 52.5547]
        }
    },
    "name": {
        "type": "Text",
        "value": "Bösebrücke Einkauf"
    }
}'
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Length: 0 Location: /v2/entities/urn:ngsi-ld:Store:003?type=Store Fiware-Correlator: f32e6e46-c520-11ec-b804-0242ac130002
```

Next, I do the query:
Query:

```
'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities' \
-d 'type=Store' \
-d 'options=keyValues'
```

And I get the response:

```
{"error":"Internal Server Error","description":"Error at querying MongoDB: Error&#61;2, Details&#61;&#39;Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest &#40;400&#41;&#59; Substatus: 0&#59; ActivityId: fde36487-2dd9-44a4-a719-99453acdd618&#59; Reason: &#40;Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest &#40;400&#41;&#59; Substatus: 0&#59; ActivityId: fde36487-2dd9-44a4-a719-99453acdd618&#59; Reason: &#40;Response status code does not indicate success: BadRequest &#40;400&#41;&#59; Substatus: 0&#59; ActivityId: fde36487-2dd9-44a4-a719-99453acdd618&#59; Reason: &#40;Message: {&quot;Errors&quot;:[&quot;The index path corresponding to the specified o"}
```

When I goto Azure cosmosdb dashboard I can see the entry present. So I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Can you please suggest how to fix this issue?

1. https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion
2. https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3797

Comment: Did you apply the recommendations described at https://stackoverflow.com/a/67060408/1485926?

Comment: Yes. 1. I added -dbDisableRetryWrites in the command to start the container. Other two are not relevant as I am not using transient entities and not using orderby param.

Comment: Although you don't use `orderBy`, ContextBroker uses `creDate` to order results by default. Thus, the `db.entities.createIndex({creDate:1})` step is pretty revelant. Please do it and tell us how it goes.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I ran the createIndex command and now I get fetch the entities. So I can close this issue for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was already posted [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72053276/connecting-fiware-orion-with-azure-cosmos-db). In this particular case, according with @anupam feedback in the question comments, the solution was this step:

> You need to create an index at `creDate` (e.g. `db.entities.createIndex({creDate:1})`) and maybe more, if you use `orderBy` param in your NGSIv2 queries. More detail [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3797#issuecomment-802060531)